# ReactJS: How to do padding inside a <footer/>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a footer with a white background with a pink box image named `pinkbox.png`. Without any padding, the pink box image sits in the upper left corner touching the footer's border.

But to create some space between them, I did padding and the pink box gets pushed inside, but then a horizontal scroll bar appears, rather than just pushing the pink box image inside.

What could be the issue? Thank you

**Here is the code:**

```
#footer {
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 100;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
//was trying to do padding: 15px; here

  .pink-box {
    width: 15;
    height: 15;
  }
}
```

And in my component:

```
  render(){

    return(
      <footer id="footer">
        <img
          className="pink-box"
          src="/img/pinkbox.png"
        />
      </footer>
    )
  }
```

Without `padding:15px;`:

[image]

With `padding: 15px;`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
#footer {
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 100;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  .pink-box {
    width: 15;
    height: 15;
  }
}
```